# Anypoint studio throws org.xml.sax.SAXParseException error

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Im new to Mule/anypoint studio platform.
When i try to run mule projcet from anypoint studio I get following error[1].
I have added that particular jar in my classpath too (as an external jar, which appears in referenced libraries section too.) So i dont think it is classpath issue.
Also, same project works for others.only for me. I believe it is some environmental issue.The xml segment is as follows(namespace is defined correctly.)
What might be the cause for this? why anypoint studio is throwing error while deploying the project to runtime?
Im using anypoint studio version 7.4.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json-logger="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json-logger"
....
<json-logger:logger doc:name="Log Get Locations  .../>

[1]aused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: There were '3' errors while parsing the given file 'implementation/impl-locations.xml'.
Full list:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 171; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'json-logger:logger'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-source, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the namespace you have to add the schema location in the xsi:schemaLocation attribute.

Example:

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd"></mule>
```

Comment: Actually no issue with my xml configs. after restarting the anypoint studio this is gone..im not sure why it caused at early stage

Comment: Maybe a change was not deployed.